# How can I read a file from a folder and put it as attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I am automating the sending of recurring mail based on an appointment of the calendar outlook. I am trying to attach an attachment to the mail that is in a folder. 
I have no ideas of how to do.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim objMsg As MailItem
  Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  Dim Groupe1 As String

    If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then

      Exit Sub

    End If


    Dim txt As String
    txt = Item.body

    Dim mail As String
    mail = Left(txt, InStr(1, txt, "<mailto", vbTextCompare) - 1)

    Dim body As String
    body = Mid(txt, InStr(1, txt, "<body>", vbTextCompare) + 6, Len(txt) - InStr(1, txt, "<body>", vbTextCompare) + 6)


    If Item.Categories = "MailAuto" Then

      objMsg.To = mail
      objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
      objMsg.body = body
      objMsg.Send

    End If

      Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 Set myAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc"
```

good luck